# PostgreSQL query for enum when value is NULL returns error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, enums

I have a PostgreSQL table `fish_table` that is set up to store values (related to my fish aquariums I have), one of which is an Enum type. I am using Java 12.

The `.sql` file defines the column as:

```
fish_domain character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
```

When I set the value I use a DTO class and have the field defined as:

```
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "fish_domain")
    private FishDomain fishDomain;
```

When I use actual values in the Enum, I am able to CRUD just fine. However, if I have NULL stored in the field, I get an error like this when I query for the field:

```
"message":"Exception while fetching data (/queryMyFishTable) : No enum constant com.myfish.domain.types.FishDomain.\\xa[...]42; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.myfish.domain.types.FishDomain.\\xa[...]42"
```

Now it seems to be calling `valueOf()` to get the Enum value for the value stored in the table, but since it is NULL I am getting that error. Since I cannot override the `valueOf()` method in the Enum, how do I prevent this error from happening? I don't mind NULL being returned as the value.

UPDATE:

Am I able to check for NULL values in my SQL SELECT query? And then exclude that field if it is NULL?

My SQL query to get the data:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM fish_table ft WHERE ft.name = :fishName", nativeQuery = true)
MyFishDTO getMyFishByName(@Param("fishName") String fishName);
```

Comment: For a check on nulls, you need IS NULL instead of = NULL

Comment: Are you using any framework like hibernate/ Spring JPA etc.?